# How to fix TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Button object

Tags: python, windows-10, pysimplegui

I was writing my PySimpleGUI program and it (Still) does not load
This is the error it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Lavoro.py", line 89, in <module>
    event = window.read()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10075, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10146, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 9886, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16866, in StartupTK
    _convert_window_to_tk(window)
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16753, in _convert_window_to_tk
    PackFormIntoFrame(window, master, window)
  File "D:\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 14943, in PackFormIntoFrame
    width, height = element_size
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Button object
```

This is the Code
I Put ??? For privacy

```
layout = [ [sg.Text('???')],
           [sg.Text('???')],
           [sg.Text('???', sg.Button('???'))],
           [sg.Text('???')],
           [sg.Text('???')] ]

window = sg.Window('???', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
```

I tried using this

```
event = window.read
values = window.read
```

It didnt work so now im stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of layout you are going for but I believe this line:

```py
[sg.Text('???', sg.Button('???'))],
```

should be

```py
[sg.Text('???'), sg.Button('???')],
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the error message clearly, but as per your code you tried using:

```
event = window.read
values = window.read
```

Try using the following:

```
while True:   
    event = window.read()
    values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Any_other_event':
        #do that action
  
window.close()
```

if this doesn't work for you, please update your question will full error message so we can look through it.

Comment: It still gives the same error il put the entire error

Comment: The main reason which causes the “cannot unpack non-iterable button object” error is when a user tries to unpack an Button value in a Python program. The unpacking is referred to as assigning multiple iterable values to a tuple or list variable using a single-line assignment statement.

Comment: @GigettoLai Marko has the exact answer